# Does the SpiraTest JUnit integration library support parameterized tests?

Tags: java, junit, spiratest

I'm using the Spiratest JUnit integration library. It's working fine for my normal test cases and test result are transmitted to SpiraTest as expected.

Now, I'am adding parametrized tests which is a feature of JUnit 4. When I add the SpiraTest annotation to a parametrized test, and run it with the Main class as documented in the SpiraTest Automated Testing Integration Guide, it fails. I get the following error messages:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.test.FibonacciTest.test0

Does the SpiraTest JUnit integration library support parameterized tests? If yes, how do I use parameterized tests with the SpiraTest JUnit integration library?

Here is my code to give you an idea what I try to accomplish:

```
  @RunWith(Parameterized.class)
  @SpiraTestConfiguration(url = URL, login = USER, password = PWD, projectId = PROJECT_ID)
  public class FibonacciTest {

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] { { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 1 }, { 3, 2 }, { 4, 3 }, { 5, 5 }, { 6, 8 } });
    }

    private int fInput;

    private int fExpected;

    public FibonacciTest(int input, int expected) {
        fInput = input;
        fExpected = expected;
    }

    @Test
    @SpiraTestCase(testCaseId=21966)
    public void test() {
        assertEquals(fExpected, compute(fInput));
    }

    private int compute(int fInput2) {
        return 1;
    }
  }
```

Here is the main class:

```
public class SpiraApplicationMain {    
    public final static String URL = "";
    public final static String USER = ";
    public final static String PWD = "";
    public final static int PROJECT_ID = 0;

    /**
     * Entry point for command line execution
     * 
     * @param args
     *            The command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Instantiate the JUnit core
        JUnitCore core = new JUnitCore();

        // Add the custom SpiraTest listener
        core.addListener(new SpiraTestListener());

        // Finally run the test fixture
        core.run(FibonacciTest.class);
    }

    /**
     * Entry point for JUnit 4.x runners
     *
     * @return Handle to the test framework
     */
    public static junit.framework.Test suite() {
        return new JUnit4TestAdapter(FibonacciTest.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you check which JUnit version your spiratest jar is working on? Basically, the exception shows that it is not supported - but maybe there is a special usage how spiratest will work fine with it.

Comment: My project uses Junit 4.12 and the spiratest integration library works with JUnit 4 as stated in the [documentation](http://www.inflectra.com/SpiraTest/Integrations/Unit-Test-Frameworks.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Spiratest integration library was not developed with that feature in mind, as explained by [Adam from Inflectra](https://www.inflectra.com/Support/Forum/spiratest/issues-questions/1213.aspx)